# Ноут не запускается с флешки

Tags: windows, bios, boot

Есть ноутбук hp620. Есть образ win10 x86 записанный на флешку. При загрузке системы, предлагается на выбор жёсткий notebook harddrive, USB harddrive, network harddrive. Хочу запустится с флешки потому выбираю USB harddrive. Но с флешки не запускается а просто запускает систему. Если флешку снять то пункт USB harddrive пропадает. Legasy mode включен. Secure boot отключен. Ничего не понимаю. Сейчас стоит win7, хочу сделать переразметку диска и поставить win10. Помогите запустить с флешки.  Записан образ с помощью Windows Creation Tool в первый раз и Rufus во второй. Результат одинаковый

Comment: А флэшка точно загрузочная?

Comment: @don Rumata ну естественно. А Rufus и Windows Creator tool создают не загрузочные флешки?

Comment: А в вопросе это было освещено?

Answer (score 0):

В биосе попробуйте выключить безопасную загрузку.
System configuration = > Secure boot

Comment: Уже сделано, не помогло. Сама загрузка с флешки предусмотрена, но при нажатии на пункт запускается система с диска