# Погас экран при обновлении Windows

Tags: windows-10, windows-7

Стояла Windows 7, решил обновить до 10 программой Помощник по обновлению. Программа проверила на совместимость, все было норм, начала установку, перезагрузила. Началась установки , а на 30% погас экран и висит так уже около часа. Это вообще норм? При обновлении другого ноутбука  такой проблемы не было. Подозреваю что это установка драйвера видео. Но сколько это может продолжаться? HP 620
UPD: хотел установить с флешки, но [вот что](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/954442/%d0%9d%d0%be%d1%83%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81-%d1%84%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%ba%d0%b8) может эти две проблемы как то связаны?

Answer (score 0):

Зажал кнопку питания, когда ноут отключился, включил его заново. На экране снова статус загрузки и все остальное нормально отображается. Обновление почти завершено.